Finding documents via objectId type via the Mongo Data API
As the title says I'm trying to 'find' Mongo documents where the tenantId (which is an objectId type) matches.
My find request:
    public async Task<IResponse> GetMongoCollection(string collectionName, string tenantId)
    {
        var data = new FindRequest
        {
            DataSource = ClusterName,
            Database = "dh2",
            Collection = collectionName,
            Filter = new ContentFilter { TenantId = new ObjectId ( tenantId)},
            Action = "find"
           
        };
        var mongoResponse = await SendDataAsync(data);
        return mongoResponse;
    }

My ContentFilter:
public class ContentFilter: IFilter
{
    [JsonProperty("icaNode")]
    public int Filter { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tenantId")]
    
    public ObjectId TenantId { get; set; }
}

Which is passed to a httpRequest (code trimmed for brevity)
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://eu-west-2.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/" + "token"+ "/endpoint/data/v1/action/find", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        };

This is a shot of a document in the collection that I would expect to be returned:

But no documents are returned but, if I change the object type in Mongo from a objectId to a string then the result is returned.
Is there a way to search for matching documents a filtering for a value stored in an Objectid? I'm obviously missing something!
Thanks,
C
